# Search for hostnames in kibana

Tags: kibana

I've tried searching for hostnames in kibana using part of the server name:

```
B-wit-a2pgw-*
```

Also I tried:

```
hostname: B-wit-a2pgw-*
```

And:

```
instance: B-wit-a2pgw-*
```

I have the time frame set to today. But nothing turns up in the kibana console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is your goal to find documents having `hostname` field set to your search pattern, or you want to get a list of all available hostnames through all documents?

Answer (score 0):

you can search it as `servername:B*wit*a2pgw*`, or if the field name is hostname then

```
hostname:B*wit*a2pgw*
```

Answer (score 0):

If your hostname field is already analyzed you can use this:

> hostname.raw: B-wit-a2pgw-*

In case isn't already analyzed you can use this:

> hostname: B-wit-a2pgw-*